# How do I use jQuery to find the element with a dynamically updated `active` class without click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a materialize css carousel on my webpage. When the carousel is rotated to the previous/next link, the class on the link in focus changes from `class = "carousel-item active"` to `class = "carousel-item"`.

My goal is to use jQuery to identify the new `active` class and display corresponding text related to that image.

I have tried using `.mousemove()` event listener to no avail.

I am testing this by logging the `itemid` of the image in focus to the console. On page load, the correct `itemid` is logged. However, when I scroll the carousel to the left or right, the new `itemid` does not log and nothing happens.

I have also tried using `hasClass()`. My confusion is not with how to identify or grab the element. It is how to have the selector continuously listening so that when one image loses the `active` class and the other now has the `active` class, the corresponding text will display.

Here is a link to the projects page I am referencing: http://www.alexandervellios.com/projects.html

Here is a code snippet of my carousel:

```
  <div class= "carousel" id="fs">
        <a class="carousel-item" href="https://butterflysocial.herokuapp.com/"><img src="../img/butterfly.jpg" itemid="1" class="responsive-img">
            <h6 class= "carouselTitle white-text">Butterfly Social</h6>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="https://bleauwonder.github.io/renegades-of-silicon-alley/"><img src="../img/compass.jpg" itemid="2" class="responsive-img">
            <h6 class= "carouselTitle white-text">Renegade TrailBrews</h6>
        </a>
    </div>
```

[Here is an image of the code on the browser with the `active` class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaPJp.png)

UPDATE: 
I have added the `click()` event listener to my jQuery and the code is now registering a change. However, it is still only logging the initial `itemid` of 1. Am I not grabbing the child element appropriately?

Here is the updated jQuery using the `.click()` event listener:

```
$(".carousel").click(function( event ) {
  if($("a.carousel-item").hasClass("active")) {
    let itemId = $("img.responsive-img").attr("itemid")
    console.log("ID: ", itemId)
  }
})
```

Comment: On your webpage, the carousel changes when I click on an item. So that's when the `active` class gets switched. So you can put the code that adds text at that same spot (I suppose it's in the button click handler).

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. I have implemented the click handler and it seems to be registering the change in class now. However, I am still only logging to the console the initial `itemid` which is 1. I edited my initial post to include the updated jQuery. @Kokodoko

Answer (score 1):

After clicking the carousel, I can observe a short delay until the element holding the 'active' class changes. I imagine the class applies after the specified transition of the carousel's scroll animation.
(Some information on that here: https://materializecss.com/carousel.html)

I can't see an event listener provided by materialize for carousel scroll animation completion, so you might have to create your own workaround. You could use setTimeout on your 'click' event listener, to check which element contains the 'active' class after the transition period. (But setTimeout is not accurately timed, so make sure you add a 100ms or so.)

```
function activeElementChanged() {
    let newElement = $("a.carousel-item.active")
    let itemId = newElement.find("img.responsive-img").attr("itemid")
    console.log("ID: ", itemId)
}

$(".carousel").click(function( event ) {
    setTimeout(activeElementChanged, 400)
}
```

Or you could use requestAnimationFrame to iterate continuously, checking if the active element has changed without listening for a click and without freezing the page's main thread.

```
let activeElement = null

function activeElementChanged(newElement) {
    activeElement = newElement
    let itemId = newElement.find("img.responsive-img").attr("itemid")
    console.log("ID: ", itemId)
}

let activeElementListener = function () {
    let currentActiveElement = $("a.carousel-item.active")
    if(currentActiveElement !== activeElement) {
        activeElementChanged(currentActiveElement)
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(activeElementListener)
}

requestAnimationFrame(activeElementListener)
```

EDIT: 
I just noticed you can get the index of the currently centered item using the materlize API. This should update straight after clicking without a delay.
I also fixed some issues with the previous code.

```
let carouselElement = $(".carousel")
let carousel = M.Carousel.getInstance(carouselElement);
let numberOfItems = ...

$(".carousel").click(function( event ) {
    let itemIndex = carousel.center
    while(itemIndex < 0)
        itemIndex += numberOfItems
    while(itemIndex >= numberOfItems)
        itemIndex -= numberOfItems
    let itemId = itemIndex + 1
    console.log("ID: ", itemId)
}
```

The 'center' property starts at zero and doesn't cycle (it goes infinitely negative as you scroll left, and infinitely positive as you go right), so you have to adjust it as shown above to get the itemId you are looking for.

Comment: Heck yeah! Thank you, this works great. I've been trying to figure this out for 5+ hours now. Finally a solution. Thank you so much! @tomaaato-xyz

Comment: Just a follow up - where did you find this information? I have been coding for a bout 10 months now and am fairly good at reading docs but I feel like I never would have figured this out. Does this just come with experience or am I just bad with materialize? haha. Thanks again!

Comment: I would definitely suggest that its a case of learning how to learn better with lots of practice. Working on high pressure projects really teaches you how to very quickly familiarise yourself with libraries and wring out issues. Also be resourceful. I make great use of console.log on various objects to quickly get a better mental picture of what's going on.